# How to take screenshot of activity with camera use cameraPreview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, screenshot

here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewfinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/preveiwarea"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewfinder">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_capture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="170dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/capture"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_photo_camera_24"
                android:text="@string/clickme" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is  my mainactivity.kt file

```
package com.example.gpsmapcameraapp

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture
import androidx.camera.core.Preview
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mPreviewView: PreviewView? = null
    private lateinit var main: View

    //   private val executor: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    private val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 1001
    private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf("android.permission.CAMERA", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(
//                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
//                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
//            ),
//            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            1
        )
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            1
        )
        mPreviewView = findViewById(R.id.viewfinder)
        main = findViewById(R.id.main)

        val captureButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_capture)
        captureButton.setOnClickListener {
            // get the bitmap of the view using
            // getScreenShotFromView method it is
            // implemented below
            val bitmap = getScreenShotFromView(main)

            // if bitmap is not null then
            // save it to gallery
            if (bitmap != null) {
                saveMediaToStorage(bitmap)
            }
        }

        //   captureImage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v -> takeScreenShot(v) })

        //       loadFirstFragments();
        //     loadSecondFragments();
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera() //start camera if permission has been granted by user
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }
    }


    private fun getScreenShotFromView(v: View): Bitmap? {

        var screenshot: Bitmap? = null
        try {
            // inflate screenshot object
            // with Bitmap.createBitmap it
            // requires three parameters
            // width and height of the view and
            // the background color
            screenshot =
                Bitmap.createBitmap(v.measuredWidth, v.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            // Now draw this bitmap on a canvas
            val canvas = Canvas(screenshot)
            v.draw(canvas)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("GFG", "Failed to capture screenshot because:" + e.message)
        }
        // return the bitmap
        return screenshot
    }

    private fun saveMediaToStorage(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        // Generating a file name
        val filename = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"

        // Output stream
        var fos: OutputStream? = null

        // For devices running android >= Q
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            // getting the contentResolver
            this.contentResolver?.also { resolver ->

                // Content resolver will process the contentvalues
                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {

                    // putting file information in content values
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                }

                // Inserting the contentValues to
                // contentResolver and getting the Uri
                val imageUri: Uri? =
                    resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

                // Opening an outputstream with the Uri that we got
                fos = imageUri?.let { resolver.openOutputStream(it) }
            }
        } else {
            // These for devices running on android < Q
            val imagesDir =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            val image = File(imagesDir, filename)
            fos = FileOutputStream(image)
        }

        fos?.use {
            // Finally writing the bitmap to the output stream that we opened
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Captured View and saved to Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }


    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            try {
                val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
                bindPreview(cameraProvider)
            } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
                // No errors need to be handled for this Future.
                // This should never be reached.
            } catch (_: InterruptedException) {
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun bindPreview(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()
        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .build()
        val builder = ImageCapture.Builder()
        val imageCapture = builder
            .setTargetRotation(this.windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation)
            .build()
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(mPreviewView!!.surfaceProvider)
        val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            this,
            cameraSelector,
            preview,
            imageAnalysis,
            imageCapture
        )
//        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beap)
//       verifyStoragePermission(this@MainActivity)
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted(): Boolean {
        for (permission in REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    permission
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }


}
```

here is build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.gpsmapcameraapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gpsmapcameraapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'

    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta05"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.2.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.2.0-beta02"


    dependencies {
        implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
        implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
        implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"

        implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
        implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"
    }
}
```

here is AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GPSMapCameraApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I just want to take screenshots of the activity including the camera where the detection is happening. I tried some tutorials on how to take screenshots. It captures all the parts of the screen but doesn't capture the camera part. It only shows a black screen. I open the camera in Preview in XML and the pass View camera will be open, but it only takes a screenshot of the activity, not take screenshot of the inside in the preview.

Answer (score 1):

try `View.drawToBitmap()` method of `View` class. Or you can use `View.getDrawingCache()` method but it is deprecated. And to use this `android:drawingCacheEnabled` attribute of `View` must be `true`.